# Creating an update script for a codeignitner application, any tutorials?

Tags: php, codeigniter, auto-update

I have an application built in codeigniter which i would like to create an upgrade script for, much like the way wordpress updates to the newest version (telling you theres an update when you log into the dashboard and you clicking on update) There is multiple installs of my CMS system and it would make life easier for people if they could update this way rather than having to keep an eye out for the update mentioned on twitter or something and then download the latest version.

The problem is im not sure where to start with this, I have googled around a bit but cannot see any information, not entirely sure what terms i should be searching too.

I have the system on github, is there a way to get updates from it?

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer , and put your application stuff into repository.

Than they can use composer update.